# JTable not showing up in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am building a simple program. I should represent data in JTable, but the table is not showing up in JFrame and I can't figure out why.

**MAIN METHOD**

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

    Stredisko prvni = new Stredisko("Krkonoše", 1, "Aldrov");
    strediska.pridejStredisko(prvni);


    panel.add(b_pridej);
    panel.add(b_smaz);
    panel.add(b_konec);

    add(new JScrollPane(tbl),BorderLayout.CENTER);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    tbl.setModel(model);


    add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setVisible(true);
    pack();
    model.fireTableDataChanged();
```

Comment: It's because you don't add that table to the frame anywhere.

Comment: Adding two components at `BorderLayout.CENTER` will only display the last added one.

Comment: Where are you adding table in your code?

Comment: thanks @berger that fixed the problem! feel free to make an answer

Comment: Okay I added this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding two components at `BorderLayout.CENTER` will only display the last added one.

Consider adding your other panel elsewhere, say `BorderLayout.NORTH` for instance.